# Netbeans IDE (HTML5) - Grant access to external folder when using Netbeans Connector

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans, webserver

In Netbeans IDE for HTML5 Web Development, how can you configure your project so that you can reference external resources (i.e. resources not located in the website root) when debugging with Netbeans Connector?

**Example:**

This is the website root:

`C:\Projects\Netbeans\MyWebsite\public_html`

In this directory there are .html, .css, .js files & subdirectories containing other resources such as images.

I have a directory:

`C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents\Media`

In this directory, there are many photos I would like to reference and use in the website - whether by uploading in HTML, CSS, or JavaScript.

I'm restricted in that I cannot relocate these photos into the website root as some of the content is generated automatically.  When debugging the website, I am not permitted to view these photos due to receiving the following error (by loading via JavaScript):

> Not allowed to load local resource: ....

For extra clarification, when you debug a website, Netbeans will startup a web-server and host it locally on port 8383.  Take a look at this website for images of what things look like: [Getting Started with HTML5 Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html).  That being said, I suspect there is a way to control what resources are hosted on this web-server, perhaps in a similar way to how Apache handles it.

Also, note that this question particularly applies to the Netbeans IDE for HTML5 Web Development and not any of the other Netbeans packages.

How can I tell Netbeans to look at my `Media` folder so I can use it's images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done using Netbeans IDE's embedded lightweight web server (the one used for running your website by default).

Luckily, Netbeans allows you to specify an external web server which will give you greater control.

1. Go to your **Project > Properties**
2. Select the **Run** category from the left column
3. Select **External** from the *Web Server* combo box.
4. Specify the URL that is configured to open the content of your Netbeans project's site root directory.

[image]

Now, granted your web server can access your Netbeans project, all you need to do is start working within Netbeans to modify your website.  When you run your website, Netbeans will send a request to your external web server to display the content.

The only thing left to do is to configure your external web server to include the additional desired folder.  How this is done depends on the web server you are using.

---

This has been tested using **Apache 2.4.16 web server**.  In order to configure properly, all that was needed to be done was to change the `httpd.conf` file so that it uses a new `DocumentRoot` directive:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Projects\Netbeans\MyWebsite\public_html"
<Directory "C:\Projects\Netbeans\MyWebsite\public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Afterwards, additional folders can be added by inserting new `Directory` directives:

```
Alias /Media"C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents\Media"
<Directory "C:\Users\Nicholas\Documents\Media">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the second snippet, the `Alias` directive controls what the name of these directory will be.  Your photos can be accessed in this manner:

`http://your_ip_address/Media/your_photo_1.png`